# Can give DialogFlow based chat-bot a name

Tags: dialogflow-es

I would like to give my dialogflow based chat-bot a name, so that when I type Mels it would recognize that I am referring to it. Is there any way to do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do it.

1. Explicit invocation : This way, user has to specifically ask to chat with your chatbot. For example, my chatbot name is "SukhiBot". If user types, "talk to SukhiBot" in GoogleAssistant, then the chatbot is started and it takes care of further conversation.
2. Implicit invocation : You define a intent specific for the trigger. e.g. if your chatbot is about providing bill/invoice information then you set specific intents with keywords around billing and invoicing. When Dialogflow determines the particular intent from user's text, your chatbot will be invoked. You can set this up in the following screen with Google Assistant.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By invoking your app via google assistant, you should use the invocation phrases. For instance:- "Ok Google, talk to **nutrition calculator"**, in this phrase, nutrition calculator is your app name.

You can set your invocation phrases in the action on google console.

Some helpful resources:-
https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/